# Seamlessly adding new fields to JSON

Tags: java, json

I am working on a project where I am already publishing a payload to a topic as follows:

```
{'a': 1, 'b':2}
```

This message is being consumed by other team. I want to add a new field to the above payload as follows:

```
{'a': 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}
```

Also I want to make sure to make this change transparent to the customer. Is there any way to do it here ?

Comment: I think this is not possible in this case if you do not share some common API model classes across your projects. The other team might use different json parsinig libraries so it basically depends on it. For them this is only a json and they should choose if fields should be ignored or mapped. Interface changes almost always require changes in consuming projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JsonObject then this is how it can be done.

```
final JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
json.addProperty("c", 3);
```

Comment: I understand it. But I would like to know, how to do it so that the change is transparent to the  consumer of the json object .

Comment: As long as client end new fields are being ignored there will be no issues. If you wanted then to start accepting the new field they need to honor it. You must be using an API  contract swagger/wadl ? If not, you need to comeup with an object which can have list of flexible fields and client can loop through. It wouldn't be otherwise possible to change the main Object without any contract change